# SQL get a column as comma-seperated values from a subquery

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, subquery

I have these tables in my postresql:-
1.Payment(id, number, amount)
2.Invoice(id, number, amount)
and a invoice_payment table to allocate payments amount to invoices
3.InvoicePayment(id, payment_id, invoice_id, amount)
Single payment can be allotted to many invoices.
Now I want payment details, but I also want invoices.number of the invoices this payment is allotted to. I am doing something like this:-

```
SELECT
    payments.number,
    payments.amount,
    (SELECT invoices.number from invoices INNER JOIN invoice_payments
     ON invoices.id = invoice_payments.invoice_id
     WHERE invoice_payments.payment_id = payments.id)
from payments
```

But it gives me error more than one row returned by a subquery. How do I make the invoice number comma-seperated for every payments row?
Sample data:-

```
Payment  
id  number  amount  
1  "Pay001" 100  
2 "Pay002" 150  
3 "Pay003" 150 
Invoice  
id number amount  
1 "INV001" 100  
2 "INV002" 200  
3 "INV003"  100  
InvoicePayment  
id payment_id invoice_id amount  
1    1          1          50  
2    1          2          50  
3    2          2          150  
4    3          1           50  
5    3          3          100  

Result:-  

payment_id payment_number amount invoices  
1          "Pay001"       100    "INV001, INV002"  
2          "Pay002"       150    "INV002"  
3          "Pay003"       150    "INV001, INV002"
```

Comment: Please add sample data for all the tables, along with the expected output.  It might be hard to give you an exact answer going only on what you showed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string_agg` function in postgres to concatenate rows, separated by chosen delimiter.

```
SELECT
    payments.number,
    payments.amount,
    (SELECT string_agg(invoices.number,',') from invoices INNER JOIN invoice_payments
     ON invoices.id = invoice_payments.invoice_id
     WHERE invoice_payments.payment_id = payments.id)
from payments
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT
    payments.number,
    payments.amount,
    inv_p.inv_no
from payments p inner join (Select invoice_payments.payment_id, string_agg(invoices.number,',') as inv_no
                            From invoices inner join invoice_payments on (invoices.id = invoice_payments.invoice_id)
                            Group by invoice_payments.payment_id) inv_p on (p.id = inv_p.payment_id)
```